# How to turn off inner padding in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I need to align table with highcharts, but chart has irregular padding on the edges, it's based on percentage, I guess.

[image]

I would like `30` to stick to the left edge of chart (close to `3`) or set it distance manually in pixels. How can I do that in highcharts?

Comment: You can edit spacing / margins parameter in chart object. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart

Comment: @SebastianBochan Either by spacing or margin I can't get closer `30` to `3`.

Comment: 1) Try startOnTick as true in xAxis
2) set minPadding as 0 on xAxis
3) use offset as in answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @SebastianBochan suggestions, this is complete solution

```
 xAxis:
        startOnTick: true
        endOnTick: true
        minPadding: 0
        maxPadding: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    yAxis: {
        offset: -15
    },
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcxfhkht/

Comment: I doesn't work as expected. It's moving whole chart content to left. I need to get rid of padding either on the left either on the tight. Moreover padding is bigger when chart gets longer.